# when the cron job start after installing new crontab?

Tags: linux, shell, cron

I need to a crontab execute each 12 hours, so I have the following:

```
 0 */12 * * * . /X.sh
```

then Linux is installing new crontab. after that, I am waiting for 2 hours and still the cron job didn't start?!

When has it to start the job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crontab entry you've written is equivalent to

```
0 0-23/12 * * * . /X.sh
```

This requests execution on the hour between midnight and 11pm, using 12-hour steps — so `cron` will run the job every day at midnight and noon.

Comment: I need to see the result as soon as possible linux time now is 9:18am, then I need to start run at 10am, and then the second one will be 10+12= 22 or 21?

Comment: is it correct now?
  0 10,22 * * *

Comment: Yes, `0 10,22 * * *` will run the job at 10am and 10pm.